# Sorting based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I am doing a exercise 
I'll fire a query on the DB and get some 500 results. Now i want to sort this list based on some conditions and present the sorted list in client side.
I am using Java/Java EE and MySQL server 5.5
Conditions are like this,
Example: Consider a table having listed with cars
So, i ll fire a query on the table and it will list some 500 cars. now i want to sort this list based on user criteria.
conditions are age of car, colour of car and facilities of cars. List should be sorted like this
First appears the list of cars which satisfies all three conditions ie., same age as mentioned by end user, same colour and with all facilities user selected.
Second appears any 2 conditions satisfying cars list and one condition not satifying.
Third appears any one condition satisfying cars list and not the other two.
And finally appears the list of cars of which no conditions are satisfied.

How can i achieve this. I have searched in google, asked in irc channels regarding this. Couldn't get any help.
I have tried using RANK function by defining the CASES and finally order by RANK. It works for me while the conditions fields (columns) are of same table. In my case the fields are from a parent table as well as its child tables which has many to one relationship with its parent. Like in this example, age and color of the cars are stored in parent table and facilities that cars has are stored in another table. I tried doing the same using inner join, but no luck.

I tried something like this:

Query:

```
select distinct t0.id,t0.name,t0.price,
CASE
WHEN   
t1.age='2' AND t1.colour='Red'  AND t2.facilities_id=9 THEN 1
WHEN   
 t1.age='2' AND t1.colour='Red' AND t2.facilities_id!=9  THEN 2 
WHEN  
t1.age='2' AND t1.colour!='Red'  AND t2.facilities_id=9  THEN 3
WHEN   
t1.age!='2' AND t1.colour='Red'  AND t2.facilities_id=9  THEN 4
WHEN   
t1.age!='2' AND t1.colour='Red'  AND t2.facilities_id!=9  THEN 5
WHEN   
t1.age='2' AND t1.colour!='Red'  AND t2.facilities_id!=9  THEN 6
WHEN   *
t1.age!='2' AND t1.colour!='Red'  AND t2.facilities_id=9  THEN 7
ELSE 8
END as pre_status
from cars_listing t0
inner join
cars_listing_details t1
on t0.id=t1.mg_listing_id
inner join
cars_facilities_listing t2 
on t1.cars_listing_id=t2.listing_id
where t0.type='new_cars'
order by pre_status
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Do you want to do something like dynamic select query which has dynamic where condition?

Comment: @djIT: if i get a working static query, i ll make it dynamic

Answer (score 4):

try ordering by something like...

```
order by
   case when first_condition then 1 else 0 end
  + case when second_condition then 1 else 0 end
  + case when third_condition then 1 else 0 end  DESC



select distinct 
      t0.id,
      t0.name,
      t0.price,
      case when t1.age = '2' then 1 else 0 end as MatchedAge,
      case when t1.colour='Red' then 1 else 0 end as MatchedColor,
      case when t2.facilities_id = 9 THEN 1 else 0 end as MatchedFacility
   from 
      cars_listing t0
         inner join cars_listing_details t1
            on t0.id = t1.mg_listing_id
            inner join cars_facilities_listing t2 
               on t1.cars_listing_id = t2.listing_id
   where 
      t0.type = 'new_cars'
   order by 
        case when t1.age = '2' then 1 else 0 end
      + case  when t1.colour='Red' then 1 else 0 end
      + case when t2.facilities_id = 9 THEN 1 else 0 end DESC
```

If one field is a higher priority -- such as a red car, you could even give that more weight than the other in the order by... So a Red car at Facility 5 would show before a Blue car at facility 9 just by changing the order by to something like

```
   order by 
        case when t1.age = '2' then 1 else 0 end
      + case  when t1.colour='Red' then 5 else 0 end  <-- applyi higher Wgt to color match vs other criteria
      + case when t2.facilities_id = 9 THEN 1 else 0 end DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.Hi i added the query which i tried. Please look into it and advice.

Comment: @NakulSargur, sorry for the delay -- what exactly is your "criteria".  A Age = 2, Red car coming from Facility #9?  ie: three criteria per your example?  And is one "weighted" higher priority than the other(s)

Comment: :We have some 10 filters in priority Criteria. For example as i mentioned, user will select 3 criteria like colour,age and facility say AC(represented by 9), i have to list all the cars matching all the 3 criteria in top followed by matching any 2 criteria... 1 criteria and finally cars where nothing is matching in his criteria..

Comment: @NakulSargur, yes, I understand. the order by condition will add a value for each criteria (ignoring the "5" weight version).  So, if only one criteria is met, it will have a total of 1, if 2, then 2, and finally 3 for all 3.  The Descending will have all the 3 count criteria listed first, then all the 2 criteria, then all the 1 criteria, and finally all other cars that had NO critieria match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Sorting works fine, but it returns duplicates rows. Anyways thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @NakulSargur, then change to SELECT DISTINCT.   If you have multiple entries, such as in the cars_listing_details table, you WOULD get multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have done Dynamic sql where condition in my project. It might help you. I have created a stored procedure for SELECT query. (I have done it in **SQL Server 2008 R2**). Tell me if you need more help.

```
USE [DATABASE_NAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCEDURE_NAME]
@Id int = NULL,
@Requester varchar(20) = NULL,
@Suggester varchar(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

    SELECT @sql='SELECT Id, Suggester, Requester from DATABASE_NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME WHERE 1=1 '
    If (@Id) IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Id=(@Id) '
    If (@Suggester) IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Suggester like (@Suggester) '
    If (@Requester) IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Requester like (@Requester) '
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id int, @Requester varchar(20), @Suggester varchar(20)', 
                   @Id, @Requester, @Suggester
END

GO
```

Here in this SP; Id,Requester,Suggester are field names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need a query like what DRapp mentioned. if you can help me with query like i have posted in my question with 2 or three fields i'll make it dynamic for 'n' fields. I just need a working static query.

Comment: @NakulSargur, you can combine mine and DRapp's coding and make your query. Just put different select statements in different case. That's it.